# Need to convert a 12V/300ma alarm output to a dry signal that will interface with my security DVR

Tags: relay

Is there a relay that will work with 12V / 300ma input to close a Normally Open output? I've been trying to make it work with Ardouino board and a HiLetgo 12V 1 Channel Relay Module With Optocoupler Isolation Support High or Low Level Trigger, but have not been able to get it to work.  Seems like there should be a simpler solution that doesn't involve a controller board.

Comment: If you’d like alternatives please describe the logic level you are trying to interface with (3.3V? 5V?) and the type of signal you need.

Comment: A small relay, or one of the common relay modules, should work - no need for an Arduino.  Show a schematic of what you tried.

Comment: Ironically your problem may actually be that you have a module containing a relay and a driver circuit which may be "getting in the way".  Your output seemingly has the capability to drive a small relay *directly*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the end product - worked as expected [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use a 12V relay - most small 12V relays will have 200 ohm or more coil resistance and thus use much less than 300mA to operate. - for 300mA coil resistance as low as 40 ohms would work.

Add a diode parralel to the relay coil to prevent back-emf problems.

Comment: Thank you.  I found an SPDT micro relay with a coil rating of 12VDC -37.5mA -320 ohms.  I think I will give that a try.